# Explain Objective C retain cycle with real world example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain-cycle

I am reading about retain cycle that,  "A retain cycle can take a few forms, but it typically means that object A retains object B, and object B retains object A, but nothing else retains object A or B". But I'm not clear about that concepts. Please can anyone explain retain cycle with real world example.

Thanks.

Comment: Retain cycles can be considered as Deadlocks. If you are not able to find a good example of retain cycle, find one for deadlock.

Comment: Retain cycle is all about memory in objective-c management we know that.If you want to know the process with a real life example.Take the case of a form filling in a hall with 1000 people and 10 pens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple example,a person lives in a department,a department have one person(Suppose have one)

```
@class Department;

@interface Person:NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)Department * department;
@end

@implementation Person
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"dealloc person");
}

@end
@interface Department: NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)Person * person;
@end

@implementation Department
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"dealloc Department");
}
@end
```

Then call it like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person * person = [[Person alloc] init];
    Department * department = [[Department alloc] init];
    person.department = department;
    department.person = person;
}
```

> You will not see dealloc log,this is the retain circle

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A retain cycle is a situation when object "First" retains object "Second", and object "Second" retains object "First" at the same time*. Here is an example:

```
@class Second;
@interface First : NSObject {
Second *second; // Instance variables are implicitly __strong
}
@end

@interface Second : NSObject {
First *first;
}
@end
```

You can fix a retain cycle in ARC by using __weak variables or weak properties for your "back links", i.e. links to direct or indirect parents in an object hierarchy:

```
__weak First *first;
```